# Create own CA and CSR with custom extension fields in final private key

Tags: ssl, openssl, tls1.2

I'm very new to certificates and have tried to read up on various tutorials for creating certificates with OpenSSL.

My idea is to be able to have a CA (for signing private certificates, CSR?), which can include custom extensions.

The use case that I'm able to deliver individual certificates for my customers, where their individual certificates contains username and password for my "cloud".

The username and password should be contained within the private certificate, maybe even encrypted if possible.

The user should then be able to use that private certificate in their applications, where the application should be able to read the username and password for use elsewhere.

I know normally one can use certificates for identification and authentication etc., but here the use case is not able to use IP traffic and share TLS connections etc., but instead needs a username and password over another wireless protocol.

Is that possible and what should I google for to be able to find something about creating such certificates?

Comment: First read the X.509 specification, especially the part about the subject / DN and extensions. If you reword this to "is it possible for an X.509 certificate to contain username / password and if so, how?" then this question might be on topic on [security.se]

Comment: A certificate is public data (so drop "private certificate" concept), as such it might not be a good idea to have any sort of username and password in it. A certificate, and because its owner has the associate private key, is normally enough to assess authentication, it is strange you need username+password in addition of that, and even more so to imagine encoding it in the certificate itself (at which point the mere certificate possession should be enough).  BTW "but here the use case is not able to use IP traffic and share TLS connections" is not clear. Not using TCP/IP or TLS??